# What window-manager is this?

Tags: debian, window-manager

**What is window manager is this picture displaying?**

I was *very* impressed by Fabrice Bellard's JavaScript "linux in browser" to put it mildly. I searched for Fabrice Bellards at Stack Overflow and you can read a lengthy discussion about it. I could put up the link but you can find it very easy by searching.

Here is the video where I found it on [youtube: running linux in browser](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gu6bdKDjoE).

I think his window manager is VERY nice. So I probably want to use it if possible, (standard gnome on Fedora and Ubuntu is boring me).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window manager he is using is [IceWM](http://www.icewm.org/).

IceWM is a pretty nice and lightweight window manager that can be very similar to the Windows95 interface. Of course it is highly customizable.

As far as I can tell, the configuration of IceWM in the video is pretty close to the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

It uses [Xephyr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xephyr).

> The desktop was rendered through Xephyr and OpenSSH tunnelling to a
>   Cygwin X11 desktop, running on Windows 7.